# How to apply Panels layouts for CiviCRM pages

Tags: 7, theming, panels, display-suite, civicrm

For CiviCRM pages Events and Contributions that has paths of e.g.

```
www.site.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1
www.site.com/civicrm/event/register?id=23&reset=1
```

And so on.

Problem is that you need to copy paste custom .php files and folders in themes dir for each form to apply custom styling, e.g. have right side and left side columns and display custom content. E.g. left side column texts and infos, descriptions and right side column contains the registration form/payments.

I can't figure out how to do that without copying multiple folders for each form and editing it each time to match the page ID.

I'm looking at the Panels and it doesn't have CiviCRM content as nodes content type to be applied and filtered out in the panels variant and etc.

Or not possible?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, it would be great to see you supporting the proposal for the new CiviCRM StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=sZxmfwEWAHDXeNHrjdyxXQ2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might also be worth your while taking a look at the CiviCRM Entity module (https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity). Not straightforward to use but might get you at least some of the way.
I think Webform and webform_civicrm modules might be the way to go for standard contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Most CiviCRM forms can be accessed with the Webform CiviCRM Integration module: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

Though the integration currently only handles on-site payment methods for contribution forms.

You can build a webform using fields from the CiviCRM form and then use panels to arrange the page, or use Webform Layout module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_layout) to arrange the form elements

Comment: If you haven't already done so, it would be great to see you supporting the proposal for a new CiviCRM StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=sZxmfwEWAHDXeNHrjdyxXQ2